# Socket connection to VM from Amazon lambda

Tags: amazon-ec2, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm trying to setup a distributed application inside lambdas. I'm having problems establishing a connection from the lambda to the outside world.

For instance, when running iperf from the lambda to an outside VM I get a timeout:

```
START RequestId: dc46db91-a948-11e7-9ad9-7b02d2e37023 Version: $LATEST
HELLO WORLD
('Running: ', './iperf3 -c 172.31.41.2 -t 3')
END RequestId: dc46db91-a948-11e7-9ad9-7b02d2e37023
REPORT RequestId: dc46db91-a948-11e7-9ad9-7b02d2e37023  Duration: 30030.15 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 1536 MB    Max Memory Used: 21 MB  
2017-10-04T21:13:55.694Z dc46db91-a948-11e7-9ad9-7b02d2e37023 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

*iperf* was compiled statically. When I run this command in a different VM it works, but it fails inside the lambda.

I don't know if this has to do with a limitation of lambdas or with permission/security configurations of my setup.

Would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: There should be more detailed logs in Cloudwatch - have you looked at them?

Comment: Thanks, I checked that and it doesn't seem to show more than the text I've pasted above.

Comment: There's no sign of anything failing... it show the Lambda code.  It looks like you aren't calling `callback` or capturing/logging any status from the external process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the right VPC/Subnet/Security group configurations for the function fixed the problem.